# Argument required not found while using Terraform validate

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

My Terraform directory structure looks something like :

```
├── deploy
│      ├── dev.tfvars
│      └── qa.tfvars
├── modules
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── bastion.tf
│       ├── db.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── public
│       ├── web.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
```

In **bastion.tf**, I am trying to call a variable from **variables.tf** like this :

```
resource "aws_eip" "bastion" {
  instance = "var.eip"
  vpc = true
}
```

where, `eip = 10.x.x.x` is set in say, **dev.tfvars**.

And the configuration for **main.tf** looks like :

```
provider "aws" {}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}

module "private" {
  source = "./modules/private"
}
```

While running **terraform validate**, it gives me an error that - *The argument "eip" is required, but no definition was found*. Even if I try giving eip to module like :

```
module "private" {
  source = "./modules/private"
  eip = var.eip
}
```

it gives me another error : [image]

*An input variable with the name "eip" has not been declared.
This variable can be declared with a variable "eip" {} block*

I have `variable "eip" {}` already defined in my **variables.tf** such that it takes the values from **.tfvars file**, but somehow it isn't. Can anyone suggest what else could I be missing?

Comment: The first error is because you have no default value for the `eip` argument for the `private` module, so you need to supply one. The second error is because you supplied an argument for `eip` to the module that is an undeclared variable. You either need to supply an argument that is defined, or to declare the `eip` variable and define a value for it.

Comment: I have the value of eip defined in .tfvars file.
What would I need to fetch the value from .tfvars and just empty declare eip like - ```variable eip {}``` in the variables.tf?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing variables declarations...

From your file structure:

```
├── deploy
│      ├── dev.tfvars
│      └── qa.tfvars
├── modules
│   ├── private
│   │   ├── bastion.tf
│       ├── db.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── public
│       ├── web.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
```

There does not seem to be a companion `variables.tf` for the `main.tf` each level needs to declare the variables that will be used by resources or submodules.

If you upload your code to GitHub and post a link I could help to get you unblocked.

Comment: I tried adding a variabless.tf file in same location as main.tf and added empty variables to pass to modules, but it did not work either and threw an error :

Error: Missing required argument
on main.tf line 9, in module "private":

module "private" {

The argument "eip" is required, but no definition was found.

Comment: @s_neenu I made a correction to your variables file
https://github.com/heldersepu/terraform-snippet/blob/master/terraform/infra/private/variables.tf
with that I can run plan without any issue

Comment: Thanks! Will the same work for ```terraform validate```? According to this the validate does not take up .tfvars values
[link]https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15733

Comment: @s_neenu yes it should ... but don't take my word for it, just clone my repo and test it